Event on clicking on labels of Doughnut chart in Primeng (Angular)

Need a method handler details, how to achieve the functionality. I tried (onDataSelect) method handler, it is not throwing an event on clicking on labels.
If options can achieve the functionality, then how to do with that options property.

Which library have you used?

Chart.js legend docs

onClick (function)
A callback that is called when a click event is registered on a label item. Arguments: [event, legendItem, legend].

You can use onClick event of chart.js legend to do this!
...
this.options = {
  cutout: '60%',
  plugins: {
    legend: {
      labels: {
        color: textColor,
      },
      onClick: (event, legendItem, legend) => {
        console.log(event, legendItem, legend)
        legend.chart.toggleDataVisibility(legendItem.index);
        legend.chart.update();
      },
    },
  },
};
...

Stackblitz Demo
